Telethon joining private channels
I tried using ImportChatInviteRequest like it says in the docs, but couldn't join public or private channels. With JoinChannelRequest I can only join public channels. Is there a way I'm missing?
CHANNEL = 'https://t.me/TEST_INVITE'
await client(JoinChannelRequest(CHANNEL))
print(f'Successfully joined channel {CHANNEL}')

Tried this code with different CHANNEL variable structures
await client(JoinChannelRequest(CHANNEL))
print(f'Successfully joined channel {CHANNEL}')

such as
CHANNEL = 'https://t.me/TEST_INVITE'
# and
CHANNEL = 'TEST_INVITE'


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include a minimal reproducible example.

Telegram private chats use a hash starting with a "+". Remove the "+" and JoinChannelRequest() works.
